# "Page cannot be displayed" when trying to access CRM from thick client (USD) after ADFS 3.0 upgrade

Tags: dynamics-crm, adfs3.0, unified-service-desk

We just upgraded to ADFS 3.0 and get "page cannot be displayed" when accessing Dynamics CRM 2015 through Unified Service Desk (thick client).

I don't receive "page can't be displayed" when accessing it through the web; only when accessing from USD.

Has anybody else encountered this and found a solution?

Is there something that needs to be reconfiged in USD?

Comment: Fiddler debugging could be beneficial here. By web, I assume you mean IE, so my further assumption is that your configuration uses the Internal WPF hosting mode instead of IE. Switching to IE hosting may also assist with troubleshooting, but this may have an impact on other areas of your configuration. If you change the hosting mode on all CRM Page controls, regression testing is recommended, but a temporary change for troubleshooting this issue could be helpful.

Comment: @Hoffma Fiddler did give some perspective.  But the behavior we are seeing is super weird.  The redirect URL to ADFS almost looks like it is cutoff (something not parsed) but when I put that URL in the web it takes me right to it.  Still troubleshooting this.

Comment: @Hoffma also important to note that Fiddler is showing a 401 error when trying to access from USD (USD showing "page not avail"), not showing a 401 from the web in Fiddler.